# Different Profile Centers for each Business Unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, profile

I need different profile centers for each business Unit.

Is there any way of customize the profile centers WITHOUT having to build up a profile center from Scratch with Ampscript?

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: No

Explanation: The initial customized preference center will have to be built with Ampscript (Or Server Side Javascript) in your enterprise account. Then you can share it, or copy, paste and adjsut it into the required business units .

Answer (score 2):

I have done this by putting the profile center's HTML in a shared content area and then calling that content area from each individual BU.    I'll pass through a variable indicating account ID which allows me to customize the logo, text..etc per brand.

Comment: That's quite a sick hack!!